# How to add custom Stylesheet before Corev15.css in SharePoint Custom HTML Master Page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have created a **custom HTML Master Page**, it's working fine, but I need to Add the custom Stylesheet Before Loading the `corev15.css`

I have added the code like below

```
 <link href="/Style Library/Branding/css/ABCLeagueOpertaionCustom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But It's render look like below.
[image]

Is this any possible way to do that, Please advise me.

Comment: please explain the reason behind adding custom style-sheet before SharePoint default CSS file ..

Comment: Thanks for the quick Response, Please check this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198792/how-to-reposition-the-custom-page-elements-and-text-styles-at-top-or-default-sho

I have added the above question in Sharepoint community and also in msdn but I didn't get any reply for that, But I read one of the article they mentioned to add the Custom CSS Before Corev15.css, 

Is this Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should follow the below points**

1. You should add the Custom Stylesheet Link before Corev15.css
2. Stylesheet in custom master page Link should have
          `ms-design-css-conversion="no"` - Tag to avoid sharePoint reorder
          the stylesheet

Example tag look like below

```
    <link href="Your Custom Stylesheet path" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
```